# How can I get data out of a string of roles separated with colons?

Tags: javascript

I have a java string with user role information separated with colons. The variable `a` could contain data like this:

```
var a = "Admin:xxxx:Data";
var a = "xxxx";
var a = "Test";
var a = "Admin"
```

I need to set another variable based on this formula which depends just on the Test, xxx and Data roles being present or not. Note I already have a check in place to ensure that Test and xxxx cannot both be present and that at least one of them must be present.

```
index = 0   if the 'Test' role appears
index = 1   if the 'xxxx' role appears
index = 100 if the 'Test' and 'Data' role appear
index = 101 if the 'xxxx' and 'Data' roles appear
```

Plus another four variables:

```
isXxxx = true if xxxx appears
isData = true if Data appears
isTest = true if Test appears
isAdmin = true if Admin appears
```

Is there a simple way that I could code this. Right now I am not sure for example how
to get out the individual roles from the variable a so even if someone could advise me on just that it would probably be enough to get me going.

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? Those are two different languages.

Comment: can tell you how to do it or tell you how to research it.... latter is better. Start by researching javascript string methods, likely come across `split()` pretty quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that you have used `var` to initialize variables, I'm assuming you have JavaScript and not Java code. Aside from that, you could do this:

```
var a = "Admin:xxxx:Data";
var parts = a.split(':');
for(part in parts) {
    console.log(parts[part]);
}
```

This code splits the string on `:` and loops over the parts.

Also, I wanted to point out that you're defining `var a` 3 times and that isn't necessary. Additionally, you're overwriting the existing value of `a` with each assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in "if 'xyz' role exists" you can use string indexOf ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)) function and check the returned value. Example:

```
var isAdmin = (a.indexOf("Admin")!=-1);
```

Then based on your "is" variables you can easily form your rules:

```
var index=-1;
if (isAdmin && isXxxx) index=666;
```

Finally, I think you should prioritize your rules. For example what if all "xxxx", "Test" and "Data" exist in the roles (the last 2 rules of the question conflict each other).

Comment: PS: Be gentle, first answer :)

Comment: This is a great solution! It is much simpler than looping over the split array parts!

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this. However instead of storing it in base-10 integers (like 1, 10, 100, etc), I did it with bitwise integers (base-2).

Here's a table of examples of various roles that could be formed from this:

```
 Bits | Data | Role
--------------------
 0000 |  0   | Empty
 0001 |  1   |   1
 0010 |  2   |   2
 0011 |  3   |  1,2
 0100 |  4   |   3
 0111 |  7   | 1,2,3
 1001 |  9   |  1,4
```

And to check that they match:

```
function hasAllBits(x, y) {
    for (; y > 0; x >>= 1, y >>= 1) // Goes until reached every bit in y
        if (y % 2 > x % 2) // modulus 2 takes last bit (even or odd)
            return false; // Only possible if y == 1 and x == 0 (y>x)
    return true; // It depleted y; x had each bit
}
console.log(hasAllBits(7, 1)); // Check if user with 0111 has role 0001, true
console.log(hasAllBits(4, 1)); // Check if user with 0100 has role 0001, false
console.log(hasAllBits(1, 7)); // Check if user with 0001 has role 0111, false
```

As for getting the titles for each bit, you'll want it to return an array (because it can return multiple roles), so this would do:

```
function getRoles(r){
  var ans=[],roles=['1st','2nd','3rd','Supreme'];
  r = r.toString(2).split('').reverse();
  for(var i in r) {
    if(r[i] == '1') {
      if(roles.length > i)
        ans.push(roles[i]);
      else
        ans.push('Unknown');
    }
  }
  return ans;

console.log(getRoles(0)); // []
console.log(getRoles(4)); // ["3rd"]
console.log(getRoles(9)); // ["1st", "Supreme"]
console.log(getRoles(63)); // ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Supreme","Unknown","Unknown"]
```